# Cut Out Middle of String

Tags: unix

This is what my data looks like

orthogroup12213.faa.aligned.treefile.rooting.0.gtpruned.rearrange.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 6.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 8.0

orthogroup12706.faa.aligned.treefile.rooting.0.gtpruned.rearrange.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

...

I want to end with something like this (without the .faa.aligned.treefile.rooting.0.gtpruned.rearrange.0) :

orthogroup12213 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 6.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 8.0

orthogroup12706 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

I have tried a variety of 'cut' functions but with no luck. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\.[^ ]*//'
```

This says, "Find the first dot, and all characters that follow it that aren't a space, and replace them with nothing."

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows 2 lines with both `.faa.aligned.treefile.rooting.0.gtpruned.rearrange.0`. When this is a fixed string AND the first part is always exact 15 positions you might use `cut`:

```
# bad solution, only cut
cut -c1-15,68- file
```

This solution can be marked as terrible. When the length of the startstring or middle part changes, you are out of order.
When you know that the string to remove starts with a dot and the first space is the next cutting point, you can use

```
# also bad
sed 's/[.]/ /' file | cut -d" " -f1,3-
```

It is nice to keep it simple with `cut`, but `cut` needs simple input.
First think what is the best way to find the middle string and use something like `sed` or `awk` for this.

```
# example with sed
str='.faa.aligned.treefile.rooting.0.gtpruned.rearrange.0'
sed 's/'$str'//' file
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you very much for such a thorough explanation : )